# CrudRepository methods (OneToMany)

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I've class called Parent which has OneToMany connection with another class 'Kid'. Parent containst a List of kids. Kids contains field 'name'. Could somebody help me with how CrudRepository method and REST method should look like ? I wanna ask for Parent, giving only kid's name to method.

So far i've got :
a) crud repository method

```
Parent findByName(String name);
```

which is giving me an error (becouse Name is not Parent's Field)

b) rest method

```
@RequestMapping("parentByKidName/{name}")
@ResponseBody 
public Parent getParentByKidName(@PathVariable String name) {
return repository.findByName(name);
```

Could somebody help me please?
    }

Comment: not possible with just attribute of child key. for that you need to add specification for search. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853085/spring-jpa-criteriabuilder-search-in-a-list/34853844#34853844